# Colliding complex shaped glb files in Three.js

Tags: three.js, collision-detection, blender

I am creating an airplane game following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ze25fsFBJMk&t=530s)
I am hoping to add a collision feature to this game so that the airplane will stop moving once it hit the terrain (rather than just flying right through it like now). This is my first time dealing with game dev and three.js, and I noticed that for gld files to collide isn't as straight forward as it seems.

Here are the code for the terrain and airplane objects. Again, this is referencing from [this repo](https://github.com/Domenicobrz/R3F-takes-flight) and I am merely trying to add some features to it as a practice.

Landscape:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";

export function Landscape(props) {
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF("../assets/models/scene.glb");
  return (
    <group {...props} dispose={null} position={[0, 0, 0]}>
      <mesh
        geometry={nodes.landscape_gltf.geometry}
        material={materials["Material.009"]}
      />
      <mesh
        geometry={nodes.landscape_borders.geometry}
        material={materials["Material.010"]}
      />
      <mesh
        geometry={nodes.trees_light.geometry}
        material={materials["Material.008"]}
      />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.water.geometry} material={materials.Water} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.water1.geometry} material={materials.Water} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.water2.geometry} material={materials.Water} />
      <mesh
        geometry={nodes.lights.geometry}
        material={materials["Material.001"]}
      />
    </group>
  );
}

useGLTF.preload("../assets/models/scene.glb");
```

Airplane:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";
import { Matrix4, Vector3, Quaternion } from "three";
import { useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { updatePlaneAxis } from "./controls";

const x = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
const y = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
const z = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);

export const planePosition = new Vector3(0, 3, 7);

const delayedRotMatrix = new Matrix4();
const delayedQuaternion = new Quaternion();

export function Airplane(props) {
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF("../assets/models/airplane.glb");
  const groupRef = useRef();
  const helixMeshRef = useRef();
  planePosition.add(new Vector3(0, 0, 0.01));

  useFrame(({ camera }) => {
    updatePlaneAxis(x, y, z, planePosition, camera);

    const rotMatrix = new Matrix4().makeBasis(x, y, z);

    const matrix = new Matrix4()
      .multiply(
        new Matrix4().makeTranslation(
          planePosition.x,
          planePosition.y,
          planePosition.z
        )
      )
      .multiply(rotMatrix);

    groupRef.current.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    groupRef.current.matrix.copy(matrix);
    groupRef.current.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true;

    var quaternionA = new Quaternion().copy(delayedQuaternion);
    var quaternionB = new Quaternion();
    quaternionB.setFromRotationMatrix(rotMatrix);

    var interpolationFactor = 0.175;
    var interpolatedQuaternion = new Quaternion().copy(quaternionA);
    interpolatedQuaternion.slerp(quaternionB, interpolationFactor);
    delayedQuaternion.copy(interpolatedQuaternion);

    delayedRotMatrix.identity();
    delayedRotMatrix.makeRotationFromQuaternion(delayedQuaternion);

    const cameraMatrix = new Matrix4()
      .multiply(
        new Matrix4().makeTranslation(
          planePosition.x,
          planePosition.y,
          planePosition.z
        )
      )
      .multiply(delayedRotMatrix)
      .multiply(new Matrix4().makeRotationX(-0.2))
      .multiply(new Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, 0.015, 0.3));

    camera.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    camera.matrix.copy(cameraMatrix);
    camera.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true;

    helixMeshRef.current.rotation.z -= 1.0;
  });

  return (
    <group ref={groupRef} position={[0, 0, 0]}>
      <group {...props} dispose={null} scale={0.01} rotation-y={Math.PI}>
        <mesh
          geometry={nodes.supports.geometry}
          material={materials["Material.004"]}
        />
        <mesh
          geometry={nodes.chassis.geometry}
          material={materials["Material.005"]}
        />
        <mesh
          geometry={nodes.helix.geometry}
          material={materials["Material.005"]}
        />
        <mesh
          geometry={nodes.helix.geometry}
          material={materials["Material.005"]}
          ref={helixMeshRef}
        />
      </group>
    </group>
  );
}

useGLTF.preload("../assets/models/airplane.glb");
```

After doing some research, I am guessing I should create some sort of shape bounders around the terrain gld for collision detection? How exactly can I do that? Are there libraries that could be utilise in my case?

Comment: Adding this as a comment because it's just an idea, not an answer. You could use a rendering trick to detect collision. Use a camera UNDER your terrain. For each frame you render for your normal camera, swap the terrain color for flat black, and the plane's color for white and render the view of the underside camera to a render target. Inspect the pixels, and if you see ANY non-black pixels, the plane has clipped through the terrain ("crashed").